# Disabling Resize of Particular Columns in Handsontable

Tags: handsontable

We're using Handsontable to display charting information in certain cells and want our users to be able to resize most columns, but not columns with charts in them.

Does HoT feature a mechanism for disabling column resizing for certain columns or previewing / cancelling column resize?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the beforeColumnResize ([View in documentation](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.7.4/Hooks.html#event:beforeColumnResize)) and return false in the method to abort the resize ;)

**EDIT**

You can use :

```
beforeColumnResize: function(currentColumn, newSize, isDoubleClick) {
    if(this.getSelected() != undefined) {
        return this.getPlugin('autoColumnSize').getColumnWidth(this.getSelected()[1]);
    }
}
```

But when no selection before resize you can't prevent it :/

Comment: That looks like it should work, but for me, it always passed in `(newColumnSize, newColumnSize, undefined)` on drag resize and `(oldSize, newSize, true)` on double click resize. This makes it understandably hard to identify which column is being resized. Additionally, returning `false` did not  prevent the application from resizing the column.

I suppose this could be an issue with an older version of HoT, but we can't easily take an update either.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, it already reported https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/3328

Comment: I have updated my post ;) but i can't do more for you :/ Sorry